# Unnecessary error messages

Tags: hold, message-coding

```
f::args="`1` is not a prorper table.";

SetAttributes[f,HoldAll]

f[tab_/;ListQ[ReleaseHold@tab]===False]:=Message[f::args,HoldForm@tab]

f[tab_]:=ListPlot[ReleaseHold@tab]

g=Table[{i,i^2},{i,10}];
```

In this code I want to `ListPlot` only proprly defined tables. If I run `f[g[[2;;,{1,2}]]]` this gives expected plot. But if I by mistake type 
`f[g[[2;;{1,2}]]]` this gives error message from `Part` and also my message from `f`, but I want in this error case to see only message from `f` and no messages from Mathematica functions. How to make `f` to behave this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have a good reason to for `HoldAll` attribute even though your example does not need it.

Before I answer let's take a look at your code:

- you don't need to use `ReleaseHold` because there is no explicit `Hold` there, the argument is held and using `Condition` or `PatternTest` will result it being evaluated anyway.
- `ListQ` should return True or False so `! ListQ[...]` is more idiomatic than `ListQ[..]===False]`

So your original example can be rewritten as:

```
f[tab_ /; !ListQ[tab] ]:=Message[f::args, HoldForm@tab]
```

Now, if you want to suppress other messages you can use `Quiet`. Those messages are issued when you are checking the condition so you can do:

```
 f[tab_ /; Quiet[!ListQ[tab]] ]:=Message[f::args, HoldForm@tab]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I have a function of two arguments (two tables, or lists) that I want to `ListPlot`. The function's body is `Manipulate` with `InputField`s for the input arguments, and other controls (ranges, labels, grids etc.). One possibility is using `InputField[..., String]` and then `ToExpression@` in `ListPlot`. I decided to try another idea of using `HoldAll` to suppress evaluation arguments in corresponding `InputField`s. So then I need `ReleaseHold` inside `Manipulate`, and I used this in my simple exmaple. Your suggestion works well, thank you!

Comment: But now I don't get how to make smth like this for checking arguments of `InputField`. If one dcides to edit initial tables from function input (in `InputField`) and makes this kind of typo--- one gets myriad error messages from Mathematica ...

Comment: Well, I can add `Enabled->False` to `InputField` to prevent erroneous editing.

Comment: @Sam_1q I find it hard to grasp your problem only from this description but I've seen your next question so let me take a look.